# Problem with Asymptote axis functions doc-s and samples

Tags: asymptote

I am trying to learn Asymptote as I use it.  I was trying to reproduce the image shown below, via Asymptote's axis (grid) functions (or any other package, such as graph.asy).  I wasn't able to understand the corresponding portion of the manual and I wasn't able to find anyplace in the Charles Staat tutorial on point.  Also, I wasn't able to find any samples that were on point.

I finally created the graph **manually,** with the following inline code.  **How could I have duplicated the graph with pre-existing Asymptote functions?**

```
\begin{asy}
size(3.3cm,3.3cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

for (int i = -12; i <= 12; ++i) {
    draw((i/2,-2pi) -- (i/2, 2pi), palegrey);
    if (i %2 == 0) { draw((i/2,-2pi) -- (i/2, 2pi), grey); }
    if (i %4 == 0) { label(string(i/2,2), (i/2, -2pi), S, fontsize(8pt)); }
}

for (int i = -2; i <= 2; ++i) {
    draw((-2pi,i*pi) -- (2pi,i*pi), grey);
    if (i == 0) 
        { label("$0$", (-2pi, 0), W, fontsize(8pt)); }
    else 
        { label(string(i,2) + "pi", (-2pi, i*pi), W, fontsize(8pt)); }
}
\end{asy}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I propose two solutions. In the first one I define the function which gives the label string (for y axis to have pi and also for x axis to have even number).

```
size(8cm,0);
import graph;
import graph_pi;

xlimits( -6, 6);
ylimits( -2pi, 2pi);

string ylab(real x)
{
string s;
s="$"+string(round(x/pi))+"\pi$";
if (abs(x)<epsilon) {s="0";}
if (round(x/pi)==1) {s="$\pi$";}
if (round(x/pi)==-1) {s="$-\pi$";}
return s;
}
string xlab(real x)
{
string s;
s=string(x);
if (round(x)%2==1) {s="";}
return s;
}
yaxis( LeftRight(), RightTicks(new string(real x) { return ylab(x);},Step=pi,pTick=black, ptick=lightgrey, extend=true));
xaxis(  BottomTop(), Ticks(new string (real x) {return xlab(x);}, Step=1, step=.5, pTick=black, ptick=lightgrey, extend=true));
```

In the second solution I use `base_pi.asy` and `graph_pi.asy` unofficial packages. It gives `grid` routine and a `labelfrac` routine to have a fraction kind label.
You can find its here http://www.piprime.fr/asymptote/unofficial-asymptote-packages/

```
size(8cm,0);
import graph;
import graph_pi;

xlimits( -6, 6);
ylimits( -2pi, 2pi);



grid(xStep=1, xstep=1/2,
     yStep=pi, ystep=pi,
     pTick=.7bp+black,
     ptick=.7bp+.7white,
     above=false
     );

yaxis( LeftRight, RightTicks(labelfrac(
    factor=pi,
    symbol="\pi",
    symbolin=true,
    zero=true),
Step=pi,pTick=black, ptick=lightgrey));
xaxis( BottomTop, LeftTicks(Label("$%.2f$"), Step=2, step=1/2, ptick=lightgrey));
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks, this will be interesting research.